# Hosting one site on two servers

Tags: apache2, juju

I want to know how host one site on two servers. I am using juju to deploy mediawiki on my maas computers in LAN. And now I have two computers with ip's like this 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.115. How can I make to be seen as one IP? I want to go one of the ip in webbrowser and I get access less load server. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Juju Charm Store has a charm for the haproxy load balancer already; you should be able todo something like:

```
juju deploy haproxy
juju add-relation haproxy mediawiki
```

You should then be able to access mediawiki through the haproxy IP address - it will automatically balance load across both of the servers you have supporting the mediawiki charm.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something called a "load balancer". Basically you will have a THIRD IP address which will be the IP address you publicly set in the DNS. This IP address will be bound to a special Apache module which will then send the visitor to either the first or the second server.

But you are OT, I believe :)

Some random links:

https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/easy_http_load_balancing_with

http://www.howtoforge.com/high_availability_loadbalanced_apache_cluster

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily "make'em seen as one IP". A third server, or one of your other servers should do the job of maintaining *load balancing*. What you want to do is to build a *cluster of computers*. I'd suggest starting off with [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster), and reading whatever every links points to.

For a better choice of a *server (this is what Apache [HttpD] is)*, try learning some about [LightTPD](http://lighttpd.net) and [NGinX](http://nginx.org). Every software has it's own benefits.

You don't necessarily have to make a cluster with every node running on bare-metal, you can  use virtualization technologies like KVM, VirtualBox and Xen to build clusters of multiple vm. [Here is an article about vm clustering with Xen](http://www.clustermonkey.net/Projects/building-a-virtual-cluster-with-xen-part-one.html).

I really recommend you to read every single webpage pointed in this article, and many more you find. But start with the Wikipedia article in the first paragraph. And don't be afraid with the amounts of information and practices and software available about this subject, it is so easy in the core.

Below are some links to things you will want to know about how to create, use and benefit cluster computing, other concepts and technologies which would bait your wonderment:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/415003/how-does-one-cluster-multiple-machines-to-act-as-one-to-run-multiple-virtual-mac
- http://serc.carleton.edu/csinparallel/vm_cluster_macalester.html
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris-cluster/documentation/zone-clusters-why-whitepaper-322070.pdf
- http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1524-how-to-create-a-vmware-cluster/
- http://gjilevski.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/virtualization-using-oracle-vm-virtualbox-for-building-two-node-oracle-rac-11gr2-11-2-0-3-cluster-on-oel-6-1-using-gns-based-on-dns-and-dhcp-with-multiple-private-interconnects-deploying-haip-feat/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1030849
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziqx2hJY8Hg !! this one is incredibly helpful and easy to understand !!

**Don't forget to have fun playing with this stuff! Because they are really fun :)**